# Get Twitter feed based on multiple hashtags

Tags: php, javascript, sockets, twitter

I am trying to build a web application that would display Twitter feed based on multiple hashtags in **real time**. Something like TweeterWall. 
I've been Googling around, but there are so many APIs that I am a bit confused.

My setup is a standard shared hosting with `PHP` and `MySQL`.

**My question**: Which method is best suited for my environment?

 Should I use Streaming API, Search API, Sockets, maybe Javascript with `setInterval()`..
i realy ont know..

Thanks for your answers.
- Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [this project](https://github.com/zkniebel/jquery-twitter-feed) on GitHub. Don't be confused by the title - it has been updated since Twitter's API update to 1.1.

The jQuery plugin on the page has been re-purposed to be a Rendering engine, i.e. it helps with rendering your feeds.

The important part, however is in the "Server-Side Examples and Setup" directory. Go there, read the SETUP_INSTRUCTIONS document, and use the code in the "Plug_and_Play/Ready_PHP.php" file as your starting point.

If you followed the instructions in the SETUP_INSTRUCTIONS document, you should only have to copy and paste the keys from Twitter into the file, along with a Twitter handle, and it should render the timeline for you.

Note that you will have to update the code to render multiple timelines, and will have to either use AJAX or some other solution for updating the timelines, to simulate real-time.

On that note, be careful not to blow the rate-cap. If you are rendering timelines for just two Twitter handles, you can update them only once every 6 seconds (best case scenario).  To do this, you will have to use a separate web service to perform the requests and then query that service from your webpage.

P.S. I am the author of that project, so if you need any help, let me know. Good luck! :)

Comment: do you have any working online examples? this look great though :D

Comment: I did, but I had to take it down, as it was on a dev-site. The Plug_And_Play/Ready_PHP.php file is actually the page that I used for the live demo. The only difference is that I removed the keys and secrets from Twitter, as well as the Twitter handle. It should only take about five minutes to set up though, and doesn't require any special server settings. Just update the file with your keys/secrets and upload it to your file-system. If you set your app up on Twitter following my instructions, it should work right away.

Comment: Actually, I do have the code up on another [dev site](http://soleracms.com/testing/PHPLive.php) right now, but it is unstyled.

Comment: great, I'll try this and if i'll have any problems i'll get back to you :D